# Find max value in a list recursively in scala

Tags: scala, recursion

I'm new to Scala, there is a better way to express this with the most basic knowledge possible?

```
 def findMax(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
      xs match {
        case x :: tail => (if (tail.length==0) x else (if(x>findMax(tail)) x else (findMax(tail))))
      }
    }
```

Comment: You should return an Option(Int), in case you get an empty list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thee are two problems here. First, you call `tail.length` which is an operation of order `O(N)`, so in the worst case this will cost you N*N steps where N is the length of the sequence. The second is that your function is not tail-recursive - you nest the `findMax` calls "from outside to inside".

The usual strategy to write the correct recursive function is

- to think about each possible pattern case: here you have either the empty list `Nil` or the non-empty list `head :: tail`. This solves your first problem.
- to carry along the temporary result (here the current guess of the maximum value) as another argument of the function. This solves your second problem.

This gives:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

@tailrec
def findMax(xs: List[Int], max: Int): Int = xs match {
  case head :: tail => findMax(tail, if (head > max) head else max)
  case Nil => max
}

val z = util.Random.shuffle(1 to 100 toList)
assert(findMax(z, Int.MinValue) == 100)
```

If you don't want to expose this additional argument, you can write an auxiliary inner function.

```
def findMax(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(ys: List[Int], max: Int): Int = ys match {
    case head :: tail => loop(tail, if (head > max) head else max)
    case Nil => max
  }
  loop(xs, Int.MinValue)
}

val z = util.Random.shuffle(1 to 100 toList)
assert(findMax(z) == 100)
```

For simplicity we return `Int.MinValue` if the list is empty. A better solution might be to throw an exception for this case.

---

The `@tailrec` annotation here is optional, it simply assures that we indeed defined a tail recursive function. This has the advantage that we cannot produce a stack overflow if the list is extremely long.

Comment: An empty list would produce Int.MinValue, the same as a non empty list of Int.MinValues.

Comment: @userunknown yes, this is an arbitrary choice. You can add `if (xs.isEmpty) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("findMax(empty)")`. See also @elm's answer for a three-way pattern match.

Answer (score 5):

Any time you're reducing a collection to a single value, consider using one of the [fold](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@fold[A1>:A](z:A1)(op:(A1,A1)=>A1):A1) functions instead of explicit recursion.

```
List(3,7,1).fold(Int.MinValue)(Math.max)
// 7
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a better approach but I think the OP is trying to learn about recursion. Also, if you use `reduce(_ max _)` then you don't need `MinValue`.

Comment: `reduce` has the same problem as OP's original code, though - you end up with a function that's partial.

Comment: Then you can use `reduceOption`. It all depends on if one wants to know if the collection was empty or just to have an integer, no matter if from list or not.

Answer (score 3):

Even I too am new to Scala (am into Haskell though!).

My attempt at this would be as below.

Note that I assume a non-empty list, since the max of an empty list does not make sense.

I first define an helper method which simply returns the max of 2 numbers.

```
def maxOf2 (x:Int, y:Int): Int = {
   if (x >= y) x
   else y
}
```

Armed with this simple function, we can build a recursive function to find the 'max' as below:

```
def findMax(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
    if (xs.tail.isEmpty)
        xs.head
    else
        maxOf2(xs.head, findMax(xs.tail))
}
```

I feel this is a pretty 'clear'(though not 'efficient') way to do it.

I wanted to make the concept of recursion obvious.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `maxOf2` is just `Math.max`

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on @[fritz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103825/fritz)'s answer. If you pass in an empty list, it will throw you a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: tail of empty list

So, keeping the algorithm intact, I made this adjustment:

```
def max(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  def maxOfTwo(x: Int, y: Int): Int = {
    if (x >= y) x else y
  }
  if (xs.isEmpty) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("What man?")
  else if (xs.size == 1) xs.head
  else maxOfTwo(xs.head, max(xs.tail))
}
```

@[fritz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103825/fritz) Thanks for the answer

Comment: `maxOfTwo` is just `Math.max`.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I know that, but since I'm copying all of fritz's code, I'm doing it

Answer (score 0):

Using pattern matching an recursion,

```
def top(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs match {
  case Nil      => sys.error("no max in empty list")
  case x :: Nil => x
  case x :: xs  => math.max(x, top(xs))
}
```

Pattern matching is used to decompose the list into head and rest. A single element list is denoted with `x :: Nil`. We recurse on the rest of the list and compare for maximum on the head item of the list at each recursive stage. To make the cases exhaustive (to make a well-defined function) we consider also empty lists (`Nil`).

Answer (score 0):

```scala
def maxl(xl: List[Int]): Int = {
  if ( (xl.head > xl.tail.head) && (xl.tail.length >= 1) )
    return xl.head
  else
    if(xl.tail.length == 1)
      xl.tail.head
    else
      maxl(xl.tail)
}
```

Comment: Hello Rahul, can you try to explain your solution and why is it better than other answers. It will help others to decide if this answer is worth upvoting.

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík I don't think my approach is better than others, the response which I had given was based on my very initial stage to Scala(I am still trying to learn it). For now I like the answer from Chris Martin, which is List(3,7,1).fold(Int.MinValue)(Math.max)